# No access to the log file for the same user group on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, file-access

When I list files as a root user:

```
root@complect-shop:~# ls -lah /www/server/php/73/var/log/
total 5.8M
drw-r----- 2 root www  4.0K Oct  8 10:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Dec 16  2019 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root www  1.5M Jan  7 12:48 php-fpm.log
-rw-r----- 1 root www  4.3M Jan  6 07:12 slow.log
root@complect-shop:~#
```

`php-fpm.log` file has access read an write for `root` user and read for `www` group.

Here is the error for user `web` which is in `www` group:

```
╭╴web@complect-shop ~/complect-import-stock-wc
╰╴16:41:03 $ tail /www/server/php/73/var/log/php-fpm.log
tail: cannot open '/www/server/php/73/var/log/php-fpm.log' for reading: Permission denied
```

Here is a proof user is in the `www` group:

```
╭╴web@complect-shop ~/complect-import-stock-wc
╰╴16:45:05 $ groups web
web : web www-data www
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file php-fpm.log will need write access as it is a log file and so allocate wrirte access to the www group

```
sudo chmod g+w /www/server/php/73/var/log/php-fpm.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The group www doesn't have execute permissions on /www/server/php/73/var folder, so, you cannot get in. Grant that permission this way:

$ sudo chmod g+x /www/server/php/73/var/log/

Comment: you missed a file or -R option

Comment: No, I didn't. And yes, I did put the wrong folder in the message but it's ok in the example.

The tail command only needs read permission on files and of course, allowed to enter the folder where the file resides. The www group already have read on file php-fpm.log:

-rw-r----- 1 root www  1.5M Jan  7 12:48 php-fpm.log
      ^
      |
     +-- www can read

but, www group doesn't have permissions to "enter" /www/server/php/73/var/log/ folder:

drw-r----- 2 root www  4.0K Oct  8 10:00 .
         ^
         |
         +-- missing "x" representing the group can enter the folder